# Stumped on this Error: ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python

I need some help with my code. I am trying to find the minimum of my code but it returns with this error:

```
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence.
```

The rest of my code works except this one error.

```
file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
total = 0
count = 0
 #Read and display the file's contents
for line in file:
    number = int(line)
    total += number
    count += 1
    max_number = max(file)
    min_number = min(file)
# close the file
file.close()
def main( ):
    print("File Name: ",file.name)
    print("Sum: ", total)
    print("Count: ", count)
    print("Average: ", total / count)
    print("Maximum: ", max_number)
    print("Minimum: ", min_number)
main( )

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tylerolznoi/Desktop/Python Projects/NumStat/numstat.py", line 13, in <module>
    #min_number = min(file)
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Please share the code and the error as text (ideally code-formatted) in your original question.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for future reference.  FYI - at first glance it looks like you are misuing the built-in `min()` function - it doesn't operate on files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, the way you are using `max()` and `min()` is probably not what you want.

`max()` and `min()` are taking in an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), which will usually be a `list` or a `str`, however, you are passing in a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object).

This is not wrong per-se but what will happen if you pass this into `max()` or `min()` is it will iterate the whole file, line by line, and try to find the `max()` or `min()` line in the whole file.

The reason why your code is failing is, in the first iteration of your `for line in file`-loop, you are calling `max(file)` followed by `min(file)`. The result is,  that `max(file)` works fine (it finds the maximum line in the file) but also exhausts the iterable `file`, which is then passed into `min()`.

The consequence is that `min()` will try to iterate that exhausted iterable which is equivalent to passing in an empty list. This is why it fails.

If you need to iterate the file several times, I would suggest using `readlines()`:

```python
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

max_number = max(lines)
min_number = min(lines)

for line in lines:
    number = int(line)
    total += number
    count += 1
```

The code above assumes that each line in the text file contains one number.

Answer (score 0):

Hi min() and max() functions return the min and max value from a set of values or from an iterable object such as python list.

Try saving each number in the file to a list and calling min and max function on that list, as follows:

```
file = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
total = 0
count = 0
num_list = []
 #Read and display the file's contents
for line in file:
    number = int(line)
    total += number
    count += 1
    num_list.append(number) # append current number to the list

max_number = max(num_list) # get max value from the list of numbers
min_number = min(num_list) # get min value from the list of numbers

# close the file
file.close()

print("File Name: ",file.name)
print("Sum: ", total)
print("Count: ", count)
print("Average: ", total / count)
print("Maximum: ", max_number)
print("Minimum: ", min_number)
```